# NSFetchResultsController time filtering predicate advice

Tags: ios, database, nspredicate

I need some advice with predicates. In my app I want to have ability to filter results by date. Before I was doing it with having 2 separate predicates and checking if a filter was set.

```
if (self.isDateFilterSet==[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO])
{

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" whoRecorded.username = %@ AND deleted=0", [self.settings.currentUser username]];
}
else
{
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" (whoRecorded.username = %@) AND (deleted = 0) AND (date =>%@) AND (date<=%@)", [self.settings.currentUser username],self.dateMinSetFilter ,self.dateMaxSetFilter];


}
```

I was cleaning up my code and decided to always keep the dates in the predicate and check for dates on every update. However when I insert new data the delegate methods are not called because date<=%@ is not satisfied.

Can you suggest me the correct way of dealing with situations like this?

Comment: What dates are you using? How does this compare to new items?

Comment: Right now in viewDidLoad I call this methods to get real max/min dates on the start    

 [self getRealDateLimits];
 self.settings.dateMinSelected=settings.dateMinReal;
 self.settings.dateMaxSelected=settings.dateMaxReal;

+ I can change those date from other view to set the filters

Comment: And I store those in "settings" singleton.

Comment: What are example values of the dates? How should the dates be changed (or should they not) when new objects are added? It isn't clear what kind of solution you're looking for...

Comment: Sorry about the poor explanation. My database stores blood glucose measurements, so the dates correspond to when the measurement was taken. in viewDidLoad, I call getRealDateLimits, which finds the current min and max date in the database, then I set those date to dateMinSelected/dateMaxSelected and use those in my predicate. However when I add a new measurement, it's date is usually going to be the new max. Thats where I get lost, because I don't know an efficient way to update the table. I can set a nsnotification and basically repeat viewDidLoad method, but I don't think it is a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user hasn't specified dates to filter with, don't use the min and max from the database. You know you want everything so set the min to `[NSDate distantPast]` and the max to `[NSDate distantFuture]` and then you guarantee to cover everything.

---

Add a method:

```
- (void)resetDateFilters {
    self.dateMinSetFilter = [NSDate distantPast];
    self.dateMaxSetFilter = [NSDate distantFuture];

    // destroy the FRC here, delete cache if necessary
}
```

Call it in view did load (this is initial setup). Call it whenever the user wants to reset filters.

Comment: So I should still keep 2 different predicates and check if filter was set?

Comment: You don't need to. Set these dates in `viewDidLoad`, and whenever the user wants to reset their filters

Comment: I am a bit lost to be honest. Can you please give me a little more detail when you have time?